# Hide WP-includes, and WP-content/uploads from WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am using WordPress, I have to hide WP-includes, and WP-content/uploads from WordPress. I have tried to add the below code in htaccess

```
Options -Indexes
```

Also, I have referred to this [link](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/disable-directory-browsing-wordpress/) but still, it's not working for me.

The below link is working

```
http://localhost:8080/wordpress/wp-includes/
```

but if I add then I can see all the files. Same for the upload folder

```
http://localhost:8080/wordpress/wp-includes/assets

http://localhost:8080/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2022/01
```

**Note**-localhost is just an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I have created a `.htaccess` file in the `wp-content/uploads` and added the below code. And it's started working

```
# Kill PHP Execution
<Files ~ ".ph(?:p[345]?|t|tml)$">
deny from all
</Files>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where does the `.htaccess` file exist on the server? Which path?

Are you sure your web server is processing this file? Are you indeed running Apache?

As long as you have a file named `.htaccess` (no spaces), and it's placed in your root HTML folder, or within both `wp-includes` and `wp-content` folders, and somewhere within the file on its own line, you have `Options -indexes`, this should be respected for all subfolders and turn off auto-indexing. Can you share the entire contents of this file, perhaps you have placed this line somewhere it's not being read.

Comment: .htccess file is located in the root folder. and file name is also correct.

Comment: @user9437856 this doesn't make any sense. `.htaccess` is automatically applied to the directory it's in, and all subdirectories. What is turning this option back on inside those subdirectories? Best solution I can think of is to define a regular expression rewrite rule matching any URL starting with `/wp-includes` and ending with `/` as opposed to a file with an extension... not 100% sure there won't be some conflict. `Redirect 301 \/wp-includes(\/.+)\/ https://yoursite.com/` and `Redirect 301 \/wp-content(\/.+)\/ https://yoursite.com/`

Comment: Not sure why it's not making sense to you. I have explained the same that I have tried.